# Call api at specific scrollpoint while scrolling table view

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios9

I have one tableview and displaying products within custom cell.

There are so many records so i am using pagination right now but i want to call api for pagination when scroll point match with tableview cell scroll point before last 3 rows remains to scroll.

In short, I want to call api before last 3 rows is remains to scroll in table.

If there is other way to do like this then it will be appreciate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you need detailed access to scroll information (i.e. "points"), note that a `UITableViewDelegate` inherits from `UIScrollViewDelegate` and can implement those methods also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `UITableView` delegate method `willDisplayCell:ForRowIndexPath:`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let needToFetchNewData = indexPath.row + 3 == datasource.count

    if needToFetchNewData {
        fetchData()
    }
}
```

I'd like to consider also a variable `isAlreadyDownloading` since the user can still scroll while you're fetching new data and it'll generate more than once the same request

Comment: yeah i tried this already, but its generating all request at a time for pagination and it will call api. but i want to call when exactly there are 3 cell remain to scroll and one by one api calling. and i would like to go for condition like == rather then >= or <=

Comment: I don't catch what you mean. Can you please provide us the code you used to do it?

Comment: This is right answer but i have to set some variables to stop calling all api at once.  @LucaD Thank you..!